# material design lite (MDL) button with icon

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

in MDL there are two options: Normal Button:

```
    <button className="mdl-button mdl-js-button">
      Continue with Facebook
    </button>
```

And Icon Button:

```
    <button className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
      <i className="material-icons">mood</i>
    </button>
```

How is it possible to have a button with icon to the very left, i.e. something like

```
    <button className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--icon-left">
      <i className="material-icons">mood</i> Continue with Facebook
    </button>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>Add to shopping cart
</button>
```

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaeWWL)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding background image:

```
background-image: 'url("/assets/images/facebook-icon.png")';
background-repeat: 'no-repeat';
background-size: 'contain',
```

Comment: @Fortega has a neater solution to this issue so I recommend that the OP mark Fortega's as the answer.

Comment: Here's a codepen to show off this method: http://codepen.io/masterdoctor/pen/egPogb